# I cannot specify sender's address when sending email through rules

Tags: rules, emails

Drupal ignores the "senders email" parameter when I send emails via rules.
I cannot even specify the "sender's email field" directly, putting directly the address like "sender@drupalsite.com" - the mail gets always sent from the default website address. (My goal is to get the email from a taxonomy term proper to a commerce billing - which I can access properly).
I tried both regular and HTML mail.
What can be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Jeeeez, it was just the configuration of the mail server on my local development machine... Everything worked as it should on the drupal side.